# How can I get all joint XYZ coordinates in ARKit 3 motion capture

Tags: swift, arkit, ios13, motion-detection

I am trying to write to get all joint XYZ coordinates in ARKit 3 motion capture to getting the XYZ to find the all angles of body. but I can't find the XYZ coordinates so cant do the next step.

I am trying to use `character!.jointTransforms` to get the joint data translation maybe is the XYZ coordinates but I tried to track a few motion but the numbers didn't change.

This is my code

```
import UIKit
import RealityKit
import ARKit
import Combine

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSessionDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!

    var character: BodyTrackedEntity?
    let characterOffset: SIMD3<Float> = [0.0, 0, 0]
    let characterAnchor = AnchorEntity()

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        arView.session.delegate = self

        guard ARBodyTrackingConfiguration.isSupported else {
            fatalError("This feature is only supported on devices with an A12 chip")
        }

        let configuration = ARBodyTrackingConfiguration()
        arView.session.run(configuration)

        arView.scene.addAnchor(characterAnchor)

        // Asynchronously load the 3D character.
        var cancellable: AnyCancellable? = nil
        cancellable = Entity.loadBodyTrackedAsync(named: "character/robot").sink(
            receiveCompletion: { completion in
                if case let .failure(error) = completion {
                    print("Error: Unable to load model: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                cancellable?.cancel()
        }, receiveValue: { (character: Entity) in
            if let character = character as? BodyTrackedEntity {
                // Scale the character to human size
                character.scale = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
                self.character = character
                cancellable?.cancel()
            } else {
                print("Error: Unable to load model as BodyTrackedEntity")
            }
        })
    }

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
        for anchor in anchors {
            guard let bodyAnchor = anchor as? ARBodyAnchor else { continue }

            let bodyPosition = simd_make_float3(bodyAnchor.transform.columns.3)
            characterAnchor.position = bodyPosition + characterOffset
            characterAnchor.orientation = Transform(matrix: bodyAnchor.transform).rotation

            if let character = character, character.parent == nil {
                characterAnchor.addChild(character)
            }

            let XYZArray = character!.jointTransforms.map({ (transform: RealityKit.Transform) -> SIMD3<Float> in
                transform.translation
            })

            print(XYZArray)
        }
    }
}
```

The code is reference by

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/capturing_body_motion_in_3d

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this library PoseKit - https://github.com/d1l4y/PoseKit

```
import PoseKit


let poseKit = PoseKit()

func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    for anchor in anchors {
        guard let bodyAnchor = anchor as? ARBodyAnchor else { continue }

        print(poseKit.BodyTrackingPosition(bodyAnchor: bodyAnchor))
    }
 }


/// Gets the **hand's** position related to the **elbow** by comparing the angle between the forearm and the upper arm.
    func ForearmToHandPos(bodyAnchor: ARBodyAnchor, forearmSubcase: ShoulderToForearmSubcase, HandTransform: simd_float4, ForearmTransform: simd_float4, ShoulderTransform: simd_float4, leftArm: Bool) -> ForearmToHandSubcase {

        let handForearmVector = bodyPart.vector(joint1: ForearmTransform, joint2: HandTransform)
        let shoulderForearmVector  = bodyPart.vector(joint1: ForearmTransform, joint2: ShoulderTransform)

        let forearmAngle = abs(bodyPart.angle(vector1: handForearmVector, vector2: shoulderForearmVector))
        let crossVector = (simd_normalize(simd_cross(handForearmVector, shoulderForearmVector))) //produto vetorial deve bastar para saber o sentido

        if simd_distance(ShoulderTransform, HandTransform) > 0.57 && forearmAngle > 125.0 {
            return .straightHorizontal
        }
        if forearmSubcase == .verticalDownDiagonalBack || forearmSubcase == .verticalDownDiagonalFront || forearmSubcase == .verticalDownParallel || forearmSubcase == .horizontalTransverse {
            return ForearmToHandDownCase(forearmAngle: forearmAngle, crossVector: crossVector, leftArm: leftArm)
        } else if leftArm {
            if crossVector.z < 0 {
                if forearmAngle > 105.0 { return .bentDownOut }
                else if forearmAngle > 80 { return .bentDown }
                else if forearmAngle > 55 { return .bentDownIn }

            } else {
                if forearmAngle > 105.0 { return .bentUpOut }
                else if forearmAngle > 80 { return .bentUp }
                else if forearmAngle > 55 { return .bentUpIn }
            }
        } else {
            if crossVector.z < 0 {
                if forearmAngle > 105.0 { return .bentUpOut }
                else if forearmAngle > 80 { return .bentUp }
                else if forearmAngle > 55 { return .bentUpIn }

            } else {
                if forearmAngle > 105.0 { return .bentDownOut }
                else if forearmAngle > 80 { return .bentDown }
                else if forearmAngle > 55 { return .bentDownIn }
            }
        }
            return .horizontalBentIn
        }
```